# Python pandas DataFrame: Check if n elements has continous value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if a column has at least one instant with 5 continous days with nonzero value. Such that in the following example, this would be false for column '1'  `result=0`, and ture for column '2' `result=1`. This code will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
days=pd.date_range('1900-1-1',periods=14,freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0], '2':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]},index=days)

col='2'     #Select any column (i.e., the result for col1 should be 0 and for col2 should be 1)
nday=5      #Number of consecutive days with nonzero values 
result=0    #If nonzero values lasted for 5 consecutive days, then result=1 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[col] ==0:   #Restart counting if nonzero vaules are not continous for five days
        nday=5
    elif row[col] ==1: #Check for continous nonzero values 
        nday-=1
    
    if nday==0:      
        result=1
        break   

print(result)
```

Is there an easier way than this long code?

Answer (score 1):

The code seems good in terms of complexity and the number of lines. Just a few suggestions, see below.

```
def has_continuous(col, ndays=5) -> bool:
   days_left = n_days
   for index, row in enumerate(col):
       if not row[col]:   #Restart counting
           days_left = n_days
       else:
           # I assume that all values are non-negative. If it is not zero, it is positive
           days_left -= 1
           if not days_left:
               return True

    return False
    
result = has_continuos(df['2'], 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are always checking for `0`, you can use `rolling` with `min`:

```
col='2'
nday=5

print (df[col].rolling(nday).min().ge(1).any())

# True
```